# Event Handling of Threads in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am new to programming.Event handling in thread can be done through Run Loops in Objective C.

I have to do `createEvent,ResetEvent,PulseEvent,BeginThread,waitforsingleObject`.

How to do this in Objective C.
Is there any material that explains well about these concepts with example other than apple docs.

Comment: This isn't enough information.  What do these things do? What are you wanting to accomplish?

Comment: I need to start a thread that does some function and checks whether the thread has reached the maximum period set for it.I cpp we start the thread by AfxBeginThread and check by waitforsingleobject.and handle events by create events.How to do the same in Objective C.

Comment: Still very unclear. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

Really not a lot of information to go on here, but heres some ideas that came to mind when reading your post.

I see three approches to this:

1) Dictionary of arrays of blocks where the key in the dictionary is the event being fired and then when the event manager gets the event it cycles over the array for that key and runs all the blocks

2) Set up a [KVO system](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html) where your events are your keys/values and your observers are your handlers

3) setup a [delegate-protocol system](http://enroyed.com/ios/delegation-pattern-in-objective-c-and-writing-custom-delegates/) so that your delegate is your handler and your protocol maps the events that can be fired

all have pros and cons, I tend toward 1 and 3 myself, but hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I assume question is related to the porting of Windows source code to Mac or iOS.

Not really full answer but you can start from here.

CreateEvent, ResetEvent, WaitForSingleObject => [NSCondition Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html)

`Event` is the unique feature of Windows but reasonably replaced with NSCondtion.

BeginThread => [NSThread Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
More specifically `+ (void)detachNewThreadSelector:(SEL)aSelector toTarget:(id)aTarget withObject:(id)anArgument` method.

`AfxBeginThread(WorkerThreadProc,NULL,THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL,0,0,NULL);`
=>
`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(WorkerThreadProc:) toTarget:self withObject:NULL];`

PulseEvent is very difficult to port to Mac or iOS.